# How SQL databases perform schema migrations?

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, b-tree

Over the past few hours I've been looking into how SQL databases perform schema migrations internally.

Looking at the documentation of SQLite and Postgres I came across a few remarks about the performance of the `ALTER TABLE` with migrations. For example:

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

My understanding so far is that SQL databases store rows in pages of fixed size. That is optimal for hard disk read speeds. From that line of thinking it seems that if the schema of a database is altered there should be a rewrite of all the table pages to accommodate for the increase/decrease of the row size but that's just naive guessing.

Any pointers to the inner workings of SQL database migration systems are very welcomed? Do they just copy all row data to temp and copy the back with the new schema? Are there any "smarter" ways / optimisations to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't really related to the ANSI/ISO SQL language.

Comment: Look in the source code for more information.

Comment: @PtitXav Assuming you are referring to SQLite, do you know where in the source code is the migration code?

Comment: You can start [here](https://www.sqlite.org/arch.html)

Comment: @PtitXav I've search though the docs and the only relevant bit I found is https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html. There's only a reference on the performance costs of migrations but nothing specific about how the process works.

Comment: Tou can check with the [file format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html).